# How to dynamically inject an object to the formArrayName in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngselect

I am loading my array of objects response into a multiselect (ng-select). My response is like this

The formModel is like this

```
clientForm = this.fb.group({
    custom : this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
      clientTaskId: [''], 
      taskName: [''],
      billableRate: [''],
      customRate: ['']
    })]),
  })
```

When I select the options in multi-select, I am not able to get the value in the formArrayName 'custom'. But when I use 'custom' as a 'formControlName' I am able to get the objects which ever I am selecting.

Here is my code :

```
import {Component, NgModule, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, FormBuilder,Validators, FormArray} from '@angular/forms';
import {NgSelectModule, NgOption} from '@ng-select/ng-select';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <form [formGroup]="clientForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(clientForm.value)">
      <ng-select 
        placeholder="Select custom rates"
        [items]="taskList"
        [multiple]="true"
        bindLabel="taskName"
        [addTag]="true"
        [closeOnSelect]="false"
        clearAllText="Clear"
        formArrayName = "custom"
        >
      </ng-select>

      <br>
      <pre>{{clientForm.value | json}}</pre>
      <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  taskList =[
    { 'clientTaskId' : '1', 'taskName': 'hardware setup', billableRate: '500', customRate: ''},
    { 'clientTaskId' : '2', 'taskName': 'software installation', billableRate: '250', customRate: ''},
    { 'clientTaskId' : '3', 'taskName': 'environment setup', billableRate: '700', customRate: ''},
    { 'clientTaskId' : '4', 'taskName': 'cafeteria setup', billableRate: '1200', customRate: ''},
    ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.taskList  
  }

  submit(formValue){
    console.log(formValue)
  }

  clientForm = this.fb.group({
    custom : this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
      clientTaskId: [''], 
      taskName: [''],
      billableRate: [''],
      customRate: ['']
    })]),
    customRate: ['']
  })
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder ) {  }
}
```

Here is the demo : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/customrate-sof2) In this demo I have given the ng-select tag with formControlName and not as formArray name to make you understand my requirement.

So, what ever object I select should be loaded in the formArrayName . I tried the adding (change) function to the ng-select but it gave a different answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly you want to use the selected items and add those to a different formarray? Cause the select can't become an array sadly.

Comment: it can be either way, either add it in a different form array or in the same Formarray which i have declared in the ng-select. I am new to reactive-forms. I do not have an idea how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

did you try putting formArrayName in a div a level up?

```
<div formArrayName="custom">
 <ng-select>...</ng-select>
</div>
```

Your select should be tied to a specific formControlName within the array if I'm reading correctly